# Why is it printing a value in my object when it doesn't meet the conditions?

Tags: arrays, react-redux, conditional-operator, redux-toolkit

I am looping through an array of objects and trying to get the right object with only that object values to print with ternary operators. I am using react-redux with redux-toolkit.

```
const initialalState = [
const products = useSelector(state => state.products)
   {
  
   categoryId: 1
   itemNumber:0
   title: "hello"
   info:"turn left here please"
   imagePath:"imagePath here"
   },
   {
   productId: 2
   categoryId: 2
   itemNumber:1
   title: "hello"
   info:"jump up and down"
   imagePath:"imagePath here"
   }, 
  {
   productId: 1
   categoryId: 1
   itemNumber:2
   title: "hello"
   info:"turn left here please"
   imagePath:"imagePath here"
   },
]
```

In my JSX I have

```
const Help = () => {
return (
<>
{products.map(product => (
<div className="" key={product.productId} >
  {product.categoryId && product.productId === 2 ? <> 

    <div> {product.title} </div>
    <div> {product.imagePath} </div>
    <div> {product.info} </div>

</div>
))}
</>: <> </>

</>
)
};

export default Help;
```

In my output I get

"""

turn left please

hello
jump up and down
image here

"""

I get all the information I want plus the "info" from the other object.

I have also tried to use a ternary operator like this but I am not sure if it is correct or not.

```
 {product.sortOrder == 0 && product.categoryId && product.categoryId == 2 ? <>
</> : <> </>
```

and

```
 { product.productId && product.categoryId == 2 ? <>
      {product.itemNumber ==0 ? <>                           
     <div> {product.title} </div>
    <div> {product.imagePath} </div>
    <div> {product.info} </div>
     </> :<> </>}

    </> : <> </>}
```

How can I set conditions to only get the information from the object I want?

Comment: You need to group the conditions before the ternary operator together with parentheses if you want all of them to apply.  I might answer but I’m lazy at the moment so I’ll suggest that you read up on Boolean logic.

Comment: Thank you. I found out I have a value in the wrong place causing it to print all info on every page.